# "For Every" in Google Sheets

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do this:

if cell B41 is greater than 0, then increase the value of this cell by 1 each time B41 is increased greater than 10 (i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40, 50...) increase the value by another 1 (i.e. 0=0, 1=1, 10, 11, 12...=1, 20, 21, 22...=2, 30,31,32,33...=3...)

```
=if(B41>0,(for every 10)+1,0)
```

I looked online for alternatives on how to do the formula and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the B41 value based on itself. That is impossible, because it would result in an infinite loop.

I think one of the following formulas should help (from your explanation, it is difficult to say what you want).

**Option 1**

```
=MAX(0,INT(B41/10))
```

---

**Option 2**

```
=IF(B41>0,INT(B41/10),0)
```

---

**Option 3**

```
=IFS(B41<1,0, B41<20,1, TRUE,INT(B41/10))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried option 3 and it's exactly what I was looking for! originally I wasn't looking to infinite loop B41 I had the data being requested from another location, but in the end, your help has made this a reality; thank you so much!